# Spring Web MVC 3.1 sound files content type decorated with UTF-8

Tags: spring, spring-mvc, utf-8

I have a Spring MVC 3.1 application, and a 3rd party application is failing because Spring decides to add `; charset=UTF-8` to requests for sound files (.mp3).

For example, "hello.mp3" is returned with a content type header of:
`audio/mpeg;charset=UTF-8`

How can I configure Spring so that it doesn't decorate the content type for .mp3 files with the `UTF-8` charset suffix ?

Comment: how do you return that file? I mean how does the controller method looks like?

Comment: This was a static file in a web folder, no controller method was used to return the request for the file.  I was able to work around this issue by changing forceEncoding to false in the CharacterEncodingFilter section of the web.xml

Comment: I just saw your comment after I provided my answer. If you have an answer to your own question, add it as an answer so that others can see it easily.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `CharacterEncodingFilter` is applied to *every* request, so each response gets the encoding appended. This is not a big problem, but having `forceEncoding=false` (which is the default) may help.